# Windows 7 can't print color

Tags: windows-7, printer, printing, network-printer

I put a new hard drive and brand new Windows 7 in an old PC and it won't print in color to our network Xerox Phaser 7750 GX printers, including the Windows test page.

The printers are fine and everyone else can print no problem.  I've uninstalled, used different printer drivers (the automatically selected & the same as a working PC), tried printer sharing - no joy.  The test page print out says color supported: no yet on the PC it says color support is on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

With Xerox network printers (I'm not sure if yours has an ethernet port, but I'm assuming it does since you indicated that multiple users have access to it) there is a Printer Preference burried somewhere that allows you to obtain information from the printer on its features.  If you can find this option, you can select "update now" (or some such similar option) and it will communicate with the printer to find out which features are available, then re-configure your driver to be consistent with this.  This should enable colour printing for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can always check the printer troubleshooter (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-printer-problems) on the Windows site, though I imagine that it's probably just the printer settings themselves that need to be adjusted.